# Order list by date (String and datetime)

Tags: python, string, sorting, datetime

```
import csv,operator
from datetime import datetime

li = [['name','01/03/2012','job'],
      ['name','02/05/2013','job'],
      ['name','03/08/2014','job']]
```

### Sorted Method:

```
sorted(li,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(row[1],'%d/%m/%Y'), reverse=True)
```

**Output:**

No error, but simply not ordered

### Itemgetter Method:

```
for x in range(1,len(li)):
    li[x][6]=datetime.strptime(li[x][6],'%d/%m/%Y')

li.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(6))
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:/rmarshall/Work For Staff/ROB/_Python/__Python Projects Code/April Signed Terms.py", line 35, in <module>
    li.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(6))
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.datetime() < str()
```

Could someone supply an example of ordering a the list li by date.  For educational purposes I would appreciate examples of both the sorted method and itemgetter method with a comparison of efficiency.

Also, by the error on the itemgetter approach, is itemgetter simply not able to handle datetime objects.

Note:  I presume the ascending or descending order doesn't matter too much in this example as it can be simply flipped with `reverse=True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
print(sorted(li, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1], '%d/%m/%Y'), reverse=True))
```

You used `row` in the lamba which might have been defined before, but will never change.

I don't see a way to use `itemgetter` here. To be honest, there is a way, but it doesn't look good.

```
key_function = lambda x: datetime.strptime(itemgetter(1)(x), '%d/%m/%Y') 
print(sorted(li, key=key_function, reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works:

```
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1], "%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=True)
[['name', '03/08/2014', 'job'], ['name', '02/05/2013', 'job'], ['name', '01/03/2
012', 'job']]
```

The problem with your use of the `sorted()` is that you're trying to create a datetime from `row[1]` which doesn't work. Change it to the `lambda` you created, as I've shown above.

You most likely have a `row` variable defined somewhere earlier, which is why it will not raise an error. However if *I* run the following:

```
>>> sorted(li,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(row[1],'%d/%m/%Y'), reverse=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'row' is not defined
```

Here's an example with `itemgetter`:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))
[['name', '01/03/2012', 'job'], ['name', '02/05/2013', 'job'], ['name', '03/08/2014', 'job']]
```

In your case it works, because your datestrings are in the correct format. It might still be prudent to convert them to datetime objects.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert `str` to `datetime`, because `sorted`, can't compare `datetime` and `str`.

[datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) use to convert `str` to `datetime` object.

You can use `list.sort` on to sort on same list.

```
In [43]: li.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1], "%d/%m/%Y"))

In [44]: li
Out[44]:
[['name', '01/03/2012', 'job'],
 ['name', '02/05/2013', 'job'],
 ['name', '03/08/2014', 'job']]
```